# how load some js(or any other) files dynamically & indicate percentage of loaded data?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, load, progress

I've a html page which must load many heavy js files at the begining. It usualy takes a lot to load all of them & user can`t see how much of these data is loaded & how much has remained!
So i need to add a simple progress bar using javascript(I mean some way to indicate amount of loaded & remaining data, the graphical presentation is not important at all, it can be as simple as a number between 1 to 100!)

I need something like this pseudo:

`var filesToLoad = ['jsFilepath/s1.js', 'jsFilepath/s2.js', 'jsFilepath/s3.js'];
showProgressBarAndBeginLoadFiles(filesToLoad);`

Any idea ?

Comment: What about the browser's progress indicator is insufficient?

Comment: No, the browser progress is not suitable at all, I want to show loaded percentage to the user

Answer (score 0):

You could put ten calls to a JavaScript function like updateProgressBar(percentage) through the files s1.js, s2.js s3.js.  In updateProgressBar function you could fill div with some indicator of the current status of the JavaScript load.  Not the cleanest way to do it but I think it would work.  Not sure if you are able to add stuff to s1.js, s2.js, s3.js in your example.

Comment: Consider that I CAN`T change content of js files